# How to use left join COUNT in sequelize? (default 0)

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to write a sequelize query but unable to get the expected result.
Sorry for my immature English skills.

My query is:

> SELECT a.album_id, a.cup_id, a.title, a.thumbnail, a.created_time, IFNULL(ai.cnt, 0) AS count FROM album AS a LEFT JOIN (SELECT album_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM album_image) AS ai ON a.album_id = ai.album_id WHERE cup_id = "gPz9fLmw";

My try:

```
const albums: Album[] = await Album.findAll({
    where: { cupId: cupId },
    attributes: { include: [[sequelize.fn("IFNULL", sequelize.col("albumImages.count"), 0), "cnt"]] },
    include: {
        model: AlbumImage,
        as: "albumImages",
        attributes: [[sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("albumImages.album_id")), "count"]],
        required: false
    }
});
```

Error:

> SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'albumImages.count' in 'field list'

My ecpect:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXsUo.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `sequence.fn("IFNULL")` doesn't seem to be using it.
I solved it using **group**.

```
const albums: Album[] = await Album.findAll({
    where: { cupId: cupId },
    attributes: { include: [[sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("albumImages.album_id")), "count"]] },
    include: {
        model: AlbumImage,
        as: "albumImages",
        attributes: []
    },
    group: "Album.album_id"
});
```